# List of UML state-machine diagram to (Java) Code (Generation) Software

Tags: java, code-generation, uml

I’m looking for software / UML tools that can generate code (including, or not, Java) from UML state machine diagrams.
Be it from diagrams modeled in the tool itself or imported as XMI or whatever.

For example,

- Visual Paradigm
- Enterprise Architect (supposedly)

can do this. Do you know any other tools?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/) ([*](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/software_development/code_generation___state_machin.html)).

Comment: Enterprise Architect can’t generate code from state diagrams. (Correct me if I’m wrong, but I did not find this functionality.)

Comment: @Kissaki, it seems that EA can do this : http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/software_development/code_generation___state_machin.html

Comment: Oh, my eyes.  That's awful looking code.

Comment: @duffymo, that's another point but it's more or less my opinion too on most of generated code.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks for pointing out. I’ll have another look at it.

Comment: I failed yet again. I now contacted their support. Let’s see what they say. It’s not easy to use at the very least; or intuitive for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Paradigm.](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) This software can generate code in different languages like: Java, C#, C++, etc.

Comment: That indeed can do it (with one of the upper licences only though). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for the very same thing.  I found [SinelaboreRT](http://www.sinelabore.com/Main/Main.html).  It runs in Java and says it's compatible with Windows, OS X, and Linux.  The Graphviz requirement took some figuring out on Windows 7 though.

It can generate C, C++, Objective-C, Ada, , Java or C# code from statemachine diagrams and seems to support a number of UML tools:

- UModel
- Magic Draw
- Enterprise Architect
- Visual Paradigm for UML
- ArgoUML
- Cadifra UML Editor
- astah* (which has a free community edition)
- Built in state diagram editor

I think the ability to directly create and design the statemachine diagram inside of the application is great.  Personally, this is the option that I use.  I've also used its ability to interactively simulate the statemachine.

Comment: It's been a while - do you still use it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list with useful comparison  -
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools

Comment: Yeah, I was going through that one (also did some corrections / improvements). But it’s bloated. And most tools providing code generation won’t offer it from state diagrams in the end …

Answer (score 0):

[FSMC+](http://ed.fbk.eu/fsmcp/last/) is an Apache licensed project that accepts a statchart in an XMI file and produces Java classes implementing the state machine.